# Improve my code to make a calculator in less and more efficient code using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

some resources say that its better and more efficient to build a calculator using objects with functions and arrays ,  like in "javascript by bits website ". how can i make  my calculator code look better?

The first time i wrote a line of code was 2 weeks ago , so it probably looks bad. I tried to make it as readable as possible hope it makes sense .

```
<html>
 <head>
   </head>
  <body>

 <input type="text" id = "in" readonly   value= "" ><input type="button"  
   value="←"  onclick='q()'>
   <br>
    <input type="button"  value="0"  onclick='s("0")'>
    <input type="button"  value="1" onclick='s("1")' > 
      <input type="button"  value="2" onclick='s("2")'>           
     <input type="button"  value="c" onclick='d("")'>    
     <br>  
       <input type="button"  value="3 "onclick='s("3")'>  
       <input type="button"  value="4 "onclick='s("4")'>  
      <input type="button"  value="5" onclick='s("5")'>  
    <input type="button"  value="+" onclick='p("+")'>  
        <br>
       <input type="button"  value="6" onclick='s("6")'>  
       <input type="button"  value="7" onclick='s("7")'>  
      <input type="button"  value="8" onclick='s("8")'>  
       <input type="button"  value="-" onclick='p("-")'>  
       <br>
      <input type="button"  value="." onclick='p(".")'>  
       <input type="button"  value="9" onclick='s("9")'>  
       <input type="button"  value="*" onclick='p("*")'>  
       <input type="button"  value="/" onclick='p("/")'> 
     <input type="button"  value="=" onclick='e("")'> 
    <script>
       // deletes the value within the text box
        function d(val){
        document.getElementById("in").value=val 
          }

        // adds to value within the text box
       function s(val){
        document.getElementById("in").value+=val;
         };

        //  backspace button
         function q(){
      var value = document.getElementById("in").value;
       document.getElementById("in").value = value.substr(0, value.length - 
        1);
       };


        // if a operator delete the last operator and add a new one
       // else add a operator
      function p(val){
        var id = document.getElementById("in").value;
          var lastChar = id.substr(id.length - 1)

       if( lastChar ==="+" || lastChar ==="-" || lastChar ==="*" ||lastChar 
       === "/"||lastChar ==="."){ 
      var value = document.getElementById("in").value;
       document.getElementById("in").value = value.substr(0, value.length - 
       1)+val;
         }

       else{    document.getElementById("in").value+=val
         }

          };


          // equal sign function 
         // evaluate if it an expression 
        // else return error
        function e(){
        try{ 
          d(eval(  document.getElementById("in").value))
          }
       catch(e){
       d("error")
        }
       };

     </script>
     </body> 
     </html>
```

Comment: Should post this to CodeReview, instead.

Comment: Could you send me a link please .

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/